# Socket Server in Hostpot with Ip static

Tags: android, android-studio

Good day
Is there any way to put the static IP of the hotspot?
because every time I turn off and on again the local network generated by the cell phone, the ip changes and the connection of the client socket must have a static ip, some help please.

I've tried everything but I still can't get it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWcGZ.jpg)

With this code I can get the ip of the socket server that is assigned by default in this case '192.168.43.173', but is there any way to set this ip statically?

```
private String getIpAddress() {
    String ip = "";
    try {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces.nextElement();
            Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface.getInetAddresses();
            while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress.nextElement();
                if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                    ip += "SiteLocalAddress: "+ inetAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        ip += "Something Wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
    }
    return ip;
}
```

Comment: Can you please write an understandable post? This is abacadabra.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.